# Formatting TextField text as Price

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to format the  textfield text when user  enter a value ..  It work perfectly but my problem is ,**If user press 1 then 2 after that decimale point . My replacement string is "12." At that time numbar is 12 .** i am not able to  take decimal point ..

```
NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:string];
```

Here is My full code,

```
#pragma mark textfieldDelgate
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{

  NSLocale *locale=[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setLocale:locale];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSString *text = [textField text];
NSString *replacementText = [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
NSMutableString *newReplacement = [[ NSMutableString alloc ] initWithString:replacementText];

NSString *currencyGroupingSeparator = numberFormatter.currencyGroupingSeparator;

[newReplacement replaceOccurrencesOfString:currencyGroupingSeparator withString:@"" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [newReplacement length])];






NSNumber * number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:newReplacement];

if (number == nil && [replacementText length]!=0) {

    return NO;
}
NSLog(@"%@",newReplacement);
text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
[textField setText:text];
return NO;

  }
```

I have also attached screenshot. 
 How can I format the string with decimal value......
 Thanks in advance

Comment: you can just restrict user to enter . in your text fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the line of code:

```
 NSNumber * number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:newReplacement];
```

does not returns nil but it removes the decimal entered by user. This is because with numberFormatter id you pass a value like '12.' or '12.0' it will remove the decimal as a part of formatting. For other values like 12.3 it will not remove decimal.

I am not able to understand your requirement for doing all this coding but if you want decimal to be there put some logic to check if number is in format of 12. or 12.0 , then escape formatting. Decimal will remain there.

Please use this code:

```
NSNumber * number;    
if ([newReplacement hasSuffix:@"."] || [newReplacement hasSuffix:@".0"]) 
{ 

 [textField setText:newReplacement]; return NO; 
} 
else 
{ 
 number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:newReplacement]; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the  reply. If user press 1 then 2 after that decimale point . My  replacement string is "12." At that time numbar is nil

Comment: i dont see it as nil, i  can only see it is removing decimal.On entering 12.12 it shows 1212. Do you see nil on pressing 12.12?

Comment: sorry number is 12 . so my concern is how can i take decimal point

Comment: Replace line of code :NSNumber * number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:newReplacement];      with this:              NSNumber * number;
    
    if ([newReplacement hasSuffix:@"."] || [newReplacement hasSuffix:@".0"]) {
         [textField setText:newReplacement];
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:newReplacement];
    }

Comment: It works like a charm. Can you add this line into you answer . i will mark as accpeted answer. Thanx..

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` instead of `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` if you're dealing with formatting money. It might Just Work™ after setting that.

But, it might not. Regardless of all that, pretty sure the reason for the behavior you're seeing is that you're not giving it a number from your string; `12` is a number, as is `12.5`, but, `12.` is not. I'm surprised its not returning `nil` outright.

If thats the case (and its still broken), than you'll probably want to special-case having the `.`  at the end, and append instead of passing it into the number formatter.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried printing your code in my log. It is working fine for me.I think there is some other type of issue.

```
NSLocale *locale=[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setLocale:locale];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber* number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"12.4"];

NSLog(@"number is %@",number);
```

log print-----

number is 12.4

Comment: Thanks for the reply . can you try this code in - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

Comment: yes I have tried and when I enter 12.5 it shows 125 in textField.it replaces .(decimal) with blank

Comment: if you input a number greater than 0 it will pass, but if you want to put say 12.09 it will always change to 12 because of the formatter which will consider it as a whole number. the reason is you put it in shouldChangeCharactersInRange which is called everytime you press a key.

Comment: you mean issue in .0 something k let me try

Comment: k now I understand what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add this in .h file

NSNumberFormatter *formatter;
    NSInteger currencyScale;
    NSString *enteredDigits;


//Add this in .m file`enter code here`
-(void)viewdidload
{
  NSNumberFormatter *aFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [aFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    currencyScale = -1 * [aFormatter maximumFractionDigits];
    self.formatter = aFormatter;
}


#pragma UItextfield Delegate

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Keep a pointer to the field, so we can resign it from a toolbar
    Field = textField;
    if(textField.text==NULL || [textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        self.enteredDigits = @"";
    //textField.text=@"";
    }


}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

}


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { //give tag to text field
    if (textField.tag==10) {
        //  self.priceInput = textField;
        // Check the length of the string
        int len=[self.enteredDigits length];
        NSLog(@"string lenght is %d",len);
        if ([string length]) {
            self.enteredDigits = [self.enteredDigits stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", [string integerValue]];
        } else {
            // This is a backspace
            NSUInteger len = [self.enteredDigits length];
            if (len > 1) {
                self.enteredDigits = [self.enteredDigits substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, len - 1)];
            } else {
                self.enteredDigits = @"";
            }
        }

        NSDecimalNumber *decimal = nil;

        if ( ![self.enteredDigits isEqualToString:@""]) {
            decimal = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.enteredDigits] decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:currencyScale];
            float deci= [decimal floatValue];
            NSLog(@"decimall==%f",deci);
        } else {
            decimal = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
        }

        // Replace the text with the localized decimal number
        float deci= [decimal floatValue];
        NSLog(@"decimall==%f",deci);
        NSString *temp = [self.formatter stringFromNumber:decimal];
        textField.text=temp;
            //NSLog(@"Text fielddddddddddddddf=%@ %@",numberText,temp);

        return NO;  
    }




    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.text=@"";
    self.enteredDigits=@"";
    NSLog(@"Clear Clicked");
    return YES;

}



I think this code will help you
```

Comment: here u get two decimal point value  for eg: 0.01,0.12,1.24,12.40 and so on